# Stored Proc (table list) - compare to DB table, new added, removed placed in different table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am passing a list into a stored procedure where it is in the form of a type (table) defined in my DB. So the parameter in is a:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DomainNames] AS TABLE(
    [Domain] [nvarchar](255) NULL
)
```

From this I need to insert/delete two tables. The first is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CompanyDomains](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmailDomain] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
)
```

For all actions relating the passed in list to the CompanyDomains table, there is a passed in CompanyId parameter and it is for rows in the CompanyDomains table where CompanyDomains.CompanyId = the @CompanyId parameter passed in.

For all rows in the passed in list that are also in CompanyDomains - I do nothing.

Where any Domain in the passed in list that is not in table CompanyDomains.EmailDomain  is added to the table CompanyDomains. So sort of an upsert except there is no update action.

For any row in CompanyDomain that is not in the list, I need to remove that row from the CompanyDomains table and upsert a new entry in this table where CompanyName comes for a @CompanyName parameter passed in.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeletedCompany](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Domain] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
)
```

I say upsert because if there is a row in that table with the same Domain name, then I update the CompanyName. Otherwise I insert a new record.

I can do all this in C# with three distinct calls (select, delete, insert/update). But I'm still learning stored procedures and I don't know how to do this. Nor do I apparently know the words to search on to find this as I've had no luck looking.

My stored procedure must run on Sql Server 2008 & Sql Azure, but no need to run elsewhere.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use `MERGE` to do update/insert/delete based on the join conditions

The first `MERGE` inserts new row or deletes a row if not found in the source ( input domain list)

The deleted domain names are stored in a temporary table

The second `MERGE` inserts the deleted record into DeletedCompany if a record with such a name doesn't exist.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddUpdateDomains
  @TableVariable DomainNames READONLY,
  @CompanyId int,
  @CompanyName nvarchar(255)

AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @DeletedDomains Table
( 
  emailDomain nvarchar(255)
) 

MERGE 
   [CompanyDomains] T
USING
   @TableVariable S
ON 
   T.CompanyId = @CompanyId
   AND T.EmailDomain = S.Domain
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
   INSERT VALUES ( @CompanyId, S.Domain)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.CompanyId  = @CompanyId THEN
   DELETE 
OUTPUT  deleted.EmailDomain INTO @DeletedDomains;



MERGE 
    DeletedCompany T
USING 
    @DeletedDomains S
ON T.CompanyName = @CompanyName
AND T.Domain = S.emailDomain
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT VALUES ( S.emailDomain, @CompanyName);



END
```